# A stochastic analysis problem about martingale

Tags: probability-theory

I am studying Le Gall's "Brownian Motion,Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus"and come across the following sentence:

In the definition of a continuous local martingale starting from 0, one can
replace “uniformly integrable martingale” by “martingale” (indeed, one can
then observe that $M^{Tn\wedge n}$is uniformly integrable, and we still have $T_n \wedge n \uparrow\infty$.)

How to understand that "one can
replace “uniformly integrable martingale” by “martingale” "I think they are not equivalent?I am confused about that.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ is a martingale, then the deterministic stopping time $\omega \mapsto n$ is a stopping time for the process. Furthermore, $M^n$ is a uniformly integrable martingale.

If now by the first definition there exists stopping times $\tau_n$ such that $({M^n})^{\tau_n} = M^{\tau_n\land n}$ is an uniformly martingale for each $n$, then this also holds true for the (not necessarily uniformly integrable) martingale $M$, since $n\land \tau_n$ is again a stopping time.

Comment: I want to ask how to prove the uniformly integrability of $M^n$?Could you tell me?

Comment: $M^{n}_t = M_{n\land t} = \mathbb{E}[M_n|\mathcal{F}_t]$

Comment: Thanks!I have known where the point is.